Unable to install python3-venv on Debian 12, getting 404 error
I tried to run sudo apt-get install python3-venv but I'm getting the following error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-pip-whl python3-setuptools-whl python3.11-venv
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-pip-whl python3-setuptools-whl python3-venv python3.11-venv
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,892 B/3,043 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,197 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 python3.11-venv amd64 3.11.2-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:5::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.11/python3.11-venv_3.11.2-6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:5::644 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

When I went to the site with directory of the missing file (http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.11/), it had these files
python3.11-venv_3.11.2-6+deb12u2_amd64.deb
python3.11-venv_3.11.9-1_amd64.deb

But apt-get was requesting
python3.11-venv_3.11.2-6_amd64.deb

I'm wondering if there's a typo or something, because the one that's in the repo has  an extra +deb12u2 that the 3.11.9-1 version doesn't have.
Also prior to running the install, I ran the following commands several times:
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a

I tried running it with the --fix-missing flag as per their instruction which gave the same error:
sudo apt-get install python3-venv --fix-missing

Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 python3.11-venv amd64 3.11.2-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:5::644 80]
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pip-whl.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.11-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.11' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.11:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.11-stdlib:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.11-minimal:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 286977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-pip-whl_23.0.1+dfsg-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pip-whl (23.0.1+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-setuptools-whl.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-setuptools-whl_66.1.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-setuptools-whl (66.1.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-venv.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-venv_3.11.2-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-venv (3.11.2-1+b1) ...
Setting up python3-setuptools-whl (66.1.1-1) ...
Setting up python3-pip-whl (23.0.1+dfsg-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-venv:
 python3-venv depends on python3.11-venv (>= 3.11.2-1~); however:
  Package python3.11-venv is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-venv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-venv
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.11/python3.11-venv_3.11.2-6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:5::644 80]
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Update:
A commenter suggested a related question which I didn't come across when debugging. In my efforts to fix the error I must have done something which corrupted the GUI. In any case, I've had quite a bit of trouble with getting a specific version of Python to work on Debian, both building from source and installing it with apt. Having spent way too many days on what took 15 minutes max on every other OS, I replaced Debian with another distro.
